# SQL: Multiple column and rows comparison and finding the exact match

Tags: sql

I have the scenario where I need to find a prefix which matches all the rows and columns under that prefix. Please see the below example to find out how the comparison to work.

My expectation is to find a matching prefix (but not in same name of prefix) which matches all the rows and columns from the 2nd table.

What is the best possible way to write a query to serve this purpose.

TABLE1:

```
accm_pfx     accum_no     accm_value
--------     --------     ----------
AA00         1            A
AA00         3            B
BB00         2            A
```

TABLE2:

```
accm_pfx     accum_no     accm_value
--------     --------     ----------
CC00         1            A
CC00         3            B
EE00         1            A
EE00         2            B
EE00         3            C
DD00         9            B
```

---

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
table1.accm_pfx   matching_accm_pfx     table1.accum_no     table1.accm_value
--------          ---------------       ----------          ----------
AA00              CC00                  1                   A
AA00              CC00                  3                   B
```

Comment: What have you tried? What RDBMS? Are the matches two way? Does it have to be 1-1 (ie 2 rows in each) or if CC00 had one more row, would it still match? Or vice versa?

Comment: I am still trying to write this query, first match the number of row count within the same prefix and then compare the rest of the rows and columns, I will post if I am able to get a breakthroug.

Comment: @KyleHale, it is one way from Table1 to Table2. There should not be  any match result if number of rows are not same (less or more). It should be exact match with number of rows and values in the rest of the column. And every prefix may have different number of rows, not always 2 rows.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements about what constitutes a match aren't clear, but this gets you most of the way there (sorry for the silly aliases, you get what you pay for:)

```
 with results as (

select 

table1.accm_prfx as a,
table2.accm_prfx as b,
table1.accum_no,
table1.accum_value,
count(1) over (partition by table1_a.accm_prfx) / count(1) over (partition by table1.accm_prfx, table1_a.accum_no, table1_a.accum_value) as TotalRowsA,
count(1) over (partition by table1.accm_prfx, table2.accm_prfx) as matches,
count(1) over (partition by table2_a.accm_prfx) / count(1) over (partition by table2.accm_prfx, table2_a.accum_no, table2_a.accum_value) as TotalRowsB




 from table1 inner join table2 on table2.accum_no = table1.accum_no and table1.accum_value = table2.accum_value
 inner join table1 table1_a on table1_a.accm_prfx = table1.accm_prfx
 inner join table2 table2_a on table2_a.accm_prfx = table2.accm_prfx
 )

 select distinct a, b, accum_no, accum_value from results
 where
 totalrowsa = totalRowsB 
 and matches  = power(totalRowsA,3)
```

Step 1: Find the matches and the the total rows in table A and B for each prefix.
Step 2: The total number of matches should be a perfect cube of the number of rows. (2 matches * 2 rows in table1 * 2 rows in table2.)

Comment: your answer is the solution I am looking for. I changed to my actual scenario and it works perfectly, thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I could be miss understanding what you're looking for, but it sounds like you want to join the two tables on accum_no and accm_value ?

```
SELECT 
    t1.accm_pfx, t2.accm_pfx, t1.accum_no, t1.accm_value
FROM 
    table1 t1
INNER JOIN
    table2 t2 
ON 
    t1.accum_no = t2.accum_no and t1.accm_value = t2.accm_value
```

Comment: No @Kyle Gobel, the one your are giving is just simple join. I am more on the finding the prefix which has same number of rows and matches all the values.

Comment: Ok, so just to make sure i'm on the right page.  You want all the rows where ``accm_pfx`` has the same number of rows (i.e AA00 has 2 rows, and CC00 has 2 rows) AND the ``accum_no``, and ``accum_value`` match for these said rows